# is map/reduce appropriate for finding the median and mode of a set of values for many records?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a set of objects in Mongodb that each have a set of values embedded in them, e.g.:

`[1.22, 12.87, 1.24, 1.24, 9.87, 1.24, 87.65] //  ... up to about 150 values`

Is a map/reduce the best solution for finding the median (average) and mode (most common value) in the embedded arrays? The reason that I ask is that the map and the reduce both have to return the same (structurally) set of values. It looks like in my case I want to take in a set of values (the array) and return a set of two values (median, mode).

If not, what's the best way to approach this? I want it to run in a rake task, if that's relevant. It'd be an overnight data crunching kind of thing.

Comment: "Is a map/reduce the best solution for finding the median (average) and mode (most common value) in the embedded arrays? " Median is NOT average, it's the value at the midpoint. So do you want the median or mean (average)?

Comment: @scotts ya caught me, I haven't taken statistics in years. I don't see how that changes the answer to the question.

Comment: Calculating the median is different from the mean because you need to sort the array of numbers

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I assume you want to find the mode & median of each document, you can do this with map reduce. In this case you calculate median & mode in the map function and reduce will return the map result untouched

```
map = function() {
   var res = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < this.marks.length; i++) {
      res = res + this.marks[i];
   }
   var median = res/this.marks.length;
   emit(this._id,{marks:this.marks,median:median});
}


reduce = function (k, values) {
    values.forEach(function(value) {
      result = value;
    });
    return result;
}
```

and for this collection

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f02be1f1ae045175f0eb9f1"), "name" : "ram", "marks" : [ 1.22, 12.87, 1.24, 1.24, 9.87, 1.24, 87.65 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f02be371ae045175f0eb9f2"), "name" : "sam", "marks" : [ 1.32, 11.87, 12.4, 4.24, 9.37, 3.24, 7.65 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f02be4c1ae045175f0eb9f3"), "name" : "pam", "marks" : [ 3.32, 10.17, 11.4, 2.24, 2.37, 3.24, 30.65 ] }
```

you can get the median by

```
  db.test.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out: { inline : 1}})

{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("4f02be1f1ae045175f0eb9f1"),
            "value" : {
                "marks" : [
                    1.22,
                    12.87,
                    1.24,
                    1.24,
                    9.87,
                    1.24,
                    87.65
                ],
                "median" : 16.475714285714286
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("4f02be371ae045175f0eb9f2"),
            "value" : {
                "marks" : [
                    1.32,
                    11.87,
                    12.4,
                    4.24,
                    9.37,
                    3.24,
                    7.65
                ],
                "median" : 7.155714285714285
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("4f02be4c1ae045175f0eb9f3"),
            "value" : {
                "marks" : [
                    3.32,
                    10.17,
                    11.4,
                    2.24,
                    2.37,
                    3.24,
                    30.65
                ],
                "median" : 9.055714285714286
            }
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 1,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 3,
        "emit" : 3,
        "reduce" : 0,
        "output" : 3
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't calculate the median, rather it calculates the mean. Median is the number in the middle position in a sorted array of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There's a key question here regarding the expected output. It's not 100% clear from your question which one you want.

Do you want **(A)**:

```
{ _id: "document1", value: { mode: 1.0, median: 10.0 } }
{ _id: "document2", value: { mode: 5.0, median: 150.0 } }
... one for each document
```

... or do you want **(B)**, the mode and median across all the combination of all arrays.

- If the answer is **(A)**, then Map/Reduce **will work**.
- If the answer is **(B)**, then Map/Reduce **will probably not work**.

If you plan to do **(A)**, please read the M/R documentation carefully and understand the limitations. While option **(A)** *can* be a Map/Reduce, it can also just be a big `for` loop with an `upsert` on the "summary" collection or even back into the original collection. This may be even more efficient.

Comment: I'm looking for option A. I ran into enough cryptic errors in the map/reduce that I decided to just do a loop with a cursor (find/ forEach/update). I think you may be right that the loop will have better or at least the same performance. Thanks for the answer tho.

Comment: `If the answer is (B), then Map/Reduce will probably not work.` - If the calculation to be done is both commutative and associative then it can done with MR. mode (most common value) is similar to [word count example](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.22.0/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3A+WordCount+v1.0), while calculating the median can be done by having one Reducers which takes the median from all the mappers and calculate the median again.

Comment: @jcollum: I honestly think the Ruby method may be better for the simple fact that you can parallelize the Ruby script and have no such option with Map / Reduce.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by read this http://www.mongovue.com/2010/11/03/yet-another-mongodb-map-reduce-tutorial/.

I think you want

1. A map stage to generate your key and single data element,
2. A reduce stage to place all the data elements into
   a data array for each key,
3. A finalize stage to perform your mean, median and mode
   operations on the entire collection.

> ### Finalize Function
>
> A finalize function may be run after reduction.
> Such a function is optional and is not necessary for many map/reduce
> cases.  The finalize function takes a key and a value, and returns a
> finalized value.
>
> `function finalize(key, value) -> final_value`
>
> Your *reduce* function may
> be called *multiple times for the same object*. **Use finalize when
> something should only be done a single time at the end; for example
> calculating an average.**

*Taken from http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce*